# NullPointerexception being throwing when adding value into a vector

Tags: java, memory-management, vector, nullpointerexception

I am trying to initialize a vector which has integers 1 to n in the form of strings for starters.

This is my declaration for the vector.

```
 Vector<String> candidatesSet,frequentItemSet,mFCandidatesSet,mFSet = new <String>Vector();
```

The loop i using to initialize is

```
for(int i=0; i<crows; i++)
        {
           candidatesSet.add(Integer.toString(i+1));
        }
```

Here we get the value of variable crowsduring runtime.

but it is throwing a NullpointerException in the line where i am adding strings to the objects.

I tried intializing the vector to a null by

```
 candidatesSet = null;
```

But it didnt work

Comment: Initializing with null will certainly guarantee a NullPointerException.

Comment: You will have to assign them as given in the answer, since as per you declaration only the variable mFSet will be assigned an empty Vector but the others won't be initialized to null by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, something like is wrong:

```
Vector<String> set = new <String>Vector();
```

The correct syntax is this:

```
Vector<String> set = new Vector<String>();
```

Second of all, if you do something like this:

```
Vector<String> set1,set2,set3,set4,set5 = new Vector<String>();
```

...only `set5` will be initialized. Each variable must be initialized independently. You *could* do something like this:

```
Vector<String> set1,set2,set3,set4,set5;
set1 = set2 = set3 = set4 = set5 = new Vector<String>();
```

...but then all of the variables would point to the same `Vector`, and modifications to one variable would affect all the others. You'll have to initialize each variable separately.

Third, doing this:

```
candidatesSet = null;
```

...does nothing if `candidatesSet` is not initialized yet, since non-primitive instance variables are initialized to null anyway. That's your problem, you're calling `.add(String)` on a null object, which cases a `NullPointerException`.

Fixing those issues will make your code work, but there's one last problem. `Vector` is a somewhat outdated class, and it has been replaced by the Java Collections API. Try using [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of `Vector`, like so:

```
List<String> candidatesSet = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will make your code more efficient and less archaic.

Comment: Thanks that worked :)
Also i was thinking that vector is a better class than ArrayList(used it earlier)

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
Vector<String> candidatesSet = new Vector<String>();
```

Before add an element

Comment: You have just declarated the vector. You must inicialize too to add any element.

Comment: OscarSan - did you know that you can **edit** your own Answers?  :-)